# Need to add count(*) to this file and an if statement

Tags: php, mysql, count

When I change `SELECT *` to `SELECT count(*)` the script stops working altogether. How to I add a count(*) to this file and a statement if row count for $user >= 20 allow to INSERT else do nothing.

```
// Include needed files

include 'mysql.php';

// Connect to MySQL

connectMySQL();

//****** SECURITY CHECK *********

session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['userid'])){
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['userid']); 

//*******************************

  // Retrieves variables through AJAX

$favid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['favid']);
// $favid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['favid']);

// Firstly, check if article is favourite or not

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ajaxfavourites WHERE user='$user' AND  favid='$favid'");
$matches = mysql_num_rows($query);

// If it is not favourited, add as favourite

if($matches == '0'){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ajaxfavourites (user, favid, exptime) VALUES ('$user', '$favid', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");

echo "";
}


// Instead, if it is favourited, then remove from favourites

if($matches != '0'){
mysql_query("DELETE FROM ajaxfavourites WHERE user='$user' AND favid='$favid'");

echo "";
}

} else {

// Someone tries to directly access the file!

echo "Invalid session!";

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: when you do `count(*)` then give a alias like this `count(*) as cnt` and then fetch data `mysql_fetch_assoc` then acces the count value `cnt`, ** stop using depreciated mysql_* functions **

Comment: Why do you want to do this. $matches = mysql_num_rows($query); , directly after the SELECT statement returns you also the number of rows. so its the same

Comment: @ɹɐqʞɐ zoɹǝɟ That's the only script I could find. I will be changing it to mysqli some day.

Comment: @BerndBuffen When I change it to `if($matches < 20)` nothing happens. Is that what you had in mind?

Answer (score 0):

try to use below query, using below query if requested user's session will be 20+ then only insert statement will execute else insert statement will be ignore.

```
INSERT INTO ajaxfavourites(USER,favid ,exptime)  
SELECT  1 AS USER, 1 AS favid, NOW() AS exptime
FROM ajaxfavourites WHERE USER=1  HAVING COUNT(*) >=20;
```

Comment: @Beginner can you double check your code? I tried it but it's not doing it. The original one is `INSERT INTO ajaxfavourites (user, favid, exptime) VALUES ('$user', '$favid', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)` I believe you missed something for it to work.

Comment: @qwikad I have rolled it back.

Comment: Well, but where did the VALUES go? Shouldn't they be there for it to work? I don't see $user $favid anywhere.

Comment: I tried it's not doing it. It's not adding anything.

Comment: By the way which line in the code do I substitute with your code? Yours looks like INSERT and SELECT joined together.

Comment: By the way, it's not what I need. I don't need entries to be ignored. I want to prevent a user from adding beyond 20 favorites to the database at any given time.

Answer (score 0):

Please do necessary steps to avoid SQL injection, also try using `mysqli_*` functions instead of `mysql_*` functions

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM ajaxfavourites WHERE user='$user' AND  favid='$favid'");
$res = mysql_fetch_array($query);

// If it is not favourited, add as favourite

if($res[cnt] == 0){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO ajaxfavourites (user, favid, exptime) VALUES ('$user', '$favid', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");

    echo "";
}

// Instead, if it is favourited, then remove from favourites

if($res[cnt] > 0){
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM ajaxfavourites WHERE user='$user' AND favid='$favid'");

    echo "";
}
```

Comment: sorry if it's a stupid question, but do I need to create a column called cnt? I tried what you suggested before and it didn't work. Will try this one. Are you saying if favorites are being added the ones that are above the count will be deleted?

Comment: Also, in your example, what will start deleting them when they reach the count of 20??

Comment: No, you do not have to create the column cnt, its created at run-time and contains the number of records in the table against your conditions. In my example if there is no record in ajaxfavourites, a new insertion is done. and a deletion is done if one or more records found. Feel free to change the condition `$res[cnt] > 0` to get your desired results

Comment: Nope, it's not working. When I change it to $res[cnt] > 20 it still allows me to add unlimited favorites, but then I can't even delete them when I click unfavorite button. Any idea why?

Comment: Changing `($res[cnt] == 0)` to `($res[cnt] < 20)` doesn't stop the entries either. Not sure what's going on. Logically it all should work. Does it matter if one column is int the other one is varchar and the third one is timestamp? It's almost like something doesn't let it to be counted or something...

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved. The reason it wasn't working was it took both values into consideration ($user and $favid). As a result it was always either 0 or 1.

I had to create another mysql query with just one value in it ($user) and then I was able to get the row count. Thanks everyone!